# Calculating statistics of interactions between football players

Tags: sql-server, social-networking

I have a table of kicks between a number of football players.  Most interactions have both a kicker and receiver, but sometimes the pass is made but never received.  The table contains 3 columns.  For purposes of the example, I have added a "PassID" column to assist with the description of the problem.

The table looks as follows:

```
create table #T (Player1 varchar(25),Action varchar(25),Player2 varchar(25),PassID int)
insert into #T select 'Jamie','Kicked to','Pierre',1
insert into #T select 'Pierre','Received from ','Jamie',1
insert into #T select 'Jamie','Kicked to ','Mohamed',2
insert into #T select 'Jamie','Received from ','Kun',3
insert into #T select 'Kun ','Kicked to','Jamie',3
insert into #T select 'Mohamed','Received from ','Pierre',4
insert into #T select 'Pierre','Kicked to','Mohamed',4
insert into #T select 'Mohamed','Kicked to','Kun',5
insert into #T select 'Jamie ','Kicked to ','Kun',6
insert into #T select 'Kun ','Received from ','Jamie',6
insert into #T select 'Jamie','Received from ','Kun',7
insert into #T select 'Kun ','Kicked to','Jamie',7
```

I have to answer the following question using SQL server:
How many unique interactions exist, where a unique interaction is defined as a kick between two players, whether completed or not and where the direction of the interaction does not matter?

In this simple example, I know the answer is 5,being:
Jamie/Pierre
Jamie/Mohamed
Jamie/Kun
Mohamed/Pierre
Mohamed/Kun

How do I extract this answer from the table using T-SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
                      WHEN Player1 > Player2 THEN CONCAT(Player1,'+',Player2) 
                      ELSE CONCAT(Player2,'+',Player1)
                      END )
FROM #T
WHERE Action = 'Kicked To';
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f6a23b/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code.

```
Select CONCAT(x.Player1,'/',x.Player2)Title from (
Select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by passid order by passid)Row from #T
)X
where Row=1
```

Comment: PassID was merely part of the explanation of the problem.  If we were to use passID, part of the problem will be to first create the correct passIDs and then solve the problem.